# search over all drives in git bash crashes - "failed to read file names from file system at or below '/': No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, git, find, msysgit, git-for-windows

I am using the git-bash for windows (what is internal msys2).

I needed to search over all of my harddrives.

When I try to run `find / -type d` (and my search patterns), the search runs over the system directories of git, and aborts the search after `/proc/registry/` with the message

`find: failed to read file names from file system at or below '/': No such file or directory`

When I run `ls -la /` I see only the system directories.
Because my home is at `/c/Users/myuser` and mount shows that other driveletters are mounted below `/` (e.g. `/c/`, `/d/` ect.) I am sure there should be a way to search in `/` and find e.g. files on `/c/` and `/d/` ect..

So the question is:

- why find aborts searching with the message?
- why the mounted windows drives are not visible for ls / find?
- Is there a way to search over all mounted windows drives with one `find` command? (without manually listing all known drive-letters)

p.s. I found out, that there is a bug-report at [MSYS2-packages#1764](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/1764) with the same error, but no real solution.

Comment: Maybe try `find /[[:lower:]]/ -type d`? Or possibly, `find / -mindepth 1 -type d`. `find` will exit if it encounters certain errors, which I guess may be caused by examining `/proc/registry` or `/` itself. [This](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/59/) bug report indicates that a similar error can also be caused if a drive is not mounted correctly.

Comment: @dan I tried, the result is `find: ‘/[[:lower:]]/’: No such file or directory`.

`find / -mindepth 1 -type d` crashes with the same error-message link I mentioned in the question

Answer (score 0):

I have no answer, why this error occours, or why the mounted drive-letters are not shown in root, but I created a workarround to search over all drives:

The command is:

`find $(mount | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | grep -x '.\{2\}' | tr '\n' ' ') -type d`

It uses a sub-command to find the mounted drives, and tells find to search in each of this locations.

**explained in detail:**

- `mount`: Shows all mounten drives in format like this `C: on /c type ntfs (binary,noacl,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)`
- `cut -d ' ' -f 3`: splits the output of mount into pieces and returns 3. col of each line
- `grep -x '.\{2\}'`: greps all lines that are exact 2 digist long (e.g. `/c`) and removes the rest
- `tr '\n' ' '`: replaces linebreak with space

The final executed command is e.g.

`find /c /d /e -type d`

if you have 3 mounted driveletters.